# AzureFunctions could not refer Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

When I tried to use `GetDefinitionAsync()` with AzureFunctions, there are following error and could not obtain data from VSTS.

> Exception while executing function: Functions.VSTSWebhookCSharp. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked whether .dll is nuget restored by AzureFunctions, but it exists in "**D:\home\data\Functions\packages\nuget\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client\14.89.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.dll**"

Do you have any idea with this error?

The code I tried is following. (It's successfully running with ASP.NET Webhook, through.)

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Configuration"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Deserialize Json
    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VSTSWebHook>(jsonContent);

    // From ApplicationSettings
    var vstsUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VstsUser"];
    var vstsPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VstsPassword"];

    // Create VSTS Connection from Json Value
    var project = new Guid(jsonObject.resource.definition.project.id);
    var definitionId = jsonObject.resource.definition.id;
    var result = jsonObject.resource.result;
    var buildId = jsonObject.resource.id;
    var build = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri("https://<YOUR TENANT>.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/"), new VssBasicCredential(vstsUser, vstsPassword));

    // Exception will happen at here.   
    // Obrain definition from VSTS
    var buildDefinition = await build.GetDefinitionAsync(project, definitionId);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
        body = $"Test Complete.",
    });
}

public class VSTSWebHook
{
    public string subscriptionId { get; set; }
    public int notificationId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string eventType { get; set; }
    public string publisherId { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
    public Detailedmessage detailedMessage { get; set; }
    public Resource resource { get; set; }
    public string resourceVersion { get; set; }
    public Resourcecontainers resourceContainers { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public string markdown { get; set; }
}

public class Detailedmessage
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public string markdown { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
    public DateTime queueTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime finishTime { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Definition definition { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string sourceBranch { get; set; }
    public string sourceVersion { get; set; }
    public Queue queue { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public Requestedfor requestedFor { get; set; }
    public Requestedby requestedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastChangedDate { get; set; }
    public Lastchangedby lastChangedBy { get; set; }
    public Orchestrationplan orchestrationPlan { get; set; }
    public Logs logs { get; set; }
    public Repository repository { get; set; }
}

public class Definition
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int revision { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Project project { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class Queue
{
    public object pool { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Requestedfor
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Requestedby
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool isContainer { get; set; }
}

public class Lastchangedby
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool isContainer { get; set; }
}

public class Orchestrationplan
{
    public string planId { get; set; }
}

public class Logs
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object clean { get; set; }
    public bool checkoutSubmodules { get; set; }
}

public class Resourcecontainers
{
    public Collection collection { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public Project1 project { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Project1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my project.json.

```
{
 "frameworks": {
   "net46":{
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" : "14.89.0",
       "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client" : "14.89.0"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

It seems like `GetDefinitionAsync()` method included in the BuildHttpClienseBase Class. So the issue would be why loading dll?

```
var t = typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClientBase);
var member = t.GetMembers(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static |
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
);
```

Result was

```
Method : CreateArtifactAsync
Method : CreateArtifactAsync
Method : CreateArtifactAsync
Method : GetArtifactAsync
Method : GetArtifactAsync
Method : GetArtifactAsync
Method : GetArtifactContentZipAsync
Method : GetArtifactContentZipAsync
Method : GetArtifactContentZipAsync
Method : GetArtifactsAsync
Method : GetArtifactsAsync
Method : GetArtifactsAsync
Method : GetBadgeAsync
Method : DeleteBuildAsync
Method : DeleteBuildAsync
Method : DeleteBuildAsync
Method : GetBuildAsync
Method : GetBuildAsync
Method : GetBuildAsync
Method : GetBuildsAsync
Method : GetBuildsAsync
Method : GetBuildsAsync
Method : QueueBuildAsync
Method : QueueBuildAsync
Method : QueueBuildAsync
Method : UpdateBuildAsync
Method : UpdateBuildAsync
Method : UpdateBuildAsync
Method : GetBuildCommitsAsync
Method : GetBuildCommitsAsync
Method : GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync
Method : GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync
Method : GetBuildControllerAsync
Method : GetBuildControllersAsync
Method : CreateDefinitionAsync
Method : CreateDefinitionAsync
Method : CreateDefinitionAsync
Method : DeleteDefinitionAsync
Method : DeleteDefinitionAsync
Method : DeleteDefinitionAsync
Method : GetDefinitionAsync
Method : GetDefinitionAsync
Method : GetDefinitionAsync
Method : GetDefinitionsAsync
Method : GetDefinitionsAsync
Method : GetDefinitionsAsync
Method : UpdateDefinitionAsync
Method : UpdateDefinitionAsync
Method : UpdateDefinitionAsync
Method : GetBuildDeploymentsAsync
Method : GetBuildDeploymentsAsync
Method : GetBuildLogAsync
Method : GetBuildLogAsync
Method : GetBuildLogsAsync
Method : GetBuildLogsAsync
Method : GetBuildLogsZipAsync
Method : GetBuildLogsZipAsync
Method : GetBuildOptionDefinitionsAsync
Method : CreateQueueAsync
Method : DeleteQueueAsync
Method : GetAgentPoolQueueAsync
Method : GetQueuesAsync
Method : GetResourceUsageAsync
Method : GetDefinitionRevisionsAsync
Method : GetDefinitionRevisionsAsync
Method : GetBuildSettingsAsync
Method : UpdateBuildSettingsAsync
Method : AddBuildTagAsync
Method : AddBuildTagAsync
Method : AddBuildTagsAsync
Method : AddBuildTagsAsync
Method : DeleteBuildTagAsync
Method : DeleteBuildTagAsync
Method : GetBuildTagsAsync
Method : GetBuildTagsAsync
Method : GetTagsAsync
Method : GetTagsAsync
Method : DeleteTemplateAsync
Method : DeleteTemplateAsync
Method : GetTemplateAsync
Method : GetTemplateAsync
Method : GetTemplatesAsync
Method : GetTemplatesAsync
Method : SaveTemplateAsync
Method : SaveTemplateAsync
Method : GetBuildTimelineAsync
Method : GetBuildTimelineAsync
Method : GetBuildWorkItemsRefsAsync
Method : GetBuildWorkItemsRefsAsync
Method : GetBuildWorkItemsRefsFromCommitsAsync
Method : GetBuildWorkItemsRefsFromCommitsAsync
Method : GetWorkItemsBetweenBuildsAsync
Method : GetWorkItemsBetweenBuildsAsync
Constructor : .ctor
Constructor : .ctor
Constructor : .ctor
Constructor : .ctor
Constructor : .ctor
NestedType : <GetArtifactContentZipAsync>d__11
NestedType : <GetArtifactContentZipAsync>d__12
NestedType : <GetArtifactContentZipAsync>d__13
NestedType : <GetBuildLogAsync>d__56
NestedType : <GetBuildLogAsync>d__57
NestedType : <GetBuildLogsZipAsync>d__60
NestedType : <GetBuildLogsZipAsync>d__61
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the contents of your project.json and project.lock.json after a restore?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Sure, I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

It resolved with AzureFunctions 0.2.

Successfully call Methods without issue.

Comment: Seems not fixed completely. But can be work by Stop/Start WebApps, not restart.